# Unsure if I encrypted external HDD correctly with LUKS

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, luks

I followed the instruction from [this page](https://www.wikihow.com/Encrypt-an-External-Hard-Drive-on-Linux).

I was unable to encrypt the the disk, but was able to encrypt its partition. I don't if it was the correct thing to do, but i did it anyway because it's not important if I mess it up as this is just a use & abuse test drive.

This is the output of `sudo fdisk -l` when the partition is locked

```
Disk model: Expansion+      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7962D4CB-AA2D-4670-8D52-61F4996F76DD

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda2  264192 7814035455 7813771264  3,7T Microsoft basic data
```

and this is the output when I open it

```
Disk model: Expansion+      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7962D4CB-AA2D-4670-8D52-61F4996F76DD

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda2  264192 7814035455 7813771264  3,7T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-3457944c-2ac9-42ec-b650-8f18fcf44425: 3,65 TiB, 4000634109952 bytes, 7813738496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Did I set it up correctly? Why is it showing both the sda2 and luks partition?

Answer (score 0):

`sda2` *is* the LUKS partition – it's where LUKS writes the encrypted data.

The `/dev/mapper/luks-*` device isn't a partition in the usual sense; it's a virtual device. LUKS (or rather, dm-crypt) doesn't replace the original device but works as a translation layer *on top* of some other device.

(It can be layered on top of any other block device – partitions, whole disks, mdraid arrays, zvols, loop devices, or all kinds of "mapper" devices (e.g. dm-raid) many of which themselves work as layers on top of something else. For example, if you ran LUKS on top of LVM as some Linux distributions do, you might have a stack "disk > partition > dm-linear > dm-crypt".)

If you had encrypted the whole disk, then its original partitions would've disappeared, but the disk itself i.e. the `sda` device would still be visible. (Though `fdisk -l` wouldn't be able to report anything useful, as instead of a typical partition table it'd directly find a LUKS header.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user1686

Comment: I used the command `sudo blkid /dev/sda2` and got the output `/dev/sda2: UUID="3457944c-2ac9-42ec-b650-8f18fcf44425" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="31d6a845-b446-4fd0-92ea-fa483691fc18"` which means it's encrypted? I also wonder why the virtual device is showing 350 gb less memory than sda2.

Comment: `TYPE="crypto_LUKS"` indeed means that blkid found a LUKS volume in that device. (I'd usually recommend `lsblk -f` instead.) How did you measure the "memory"? Your fdisk output shows both devices as being nearly the same size (the LUKS virtual device is exactly 16 MB smaller than its backing device).

Comment: Sorry, I thought TiB was the same as TB, but how did calculate that the memory is 16 MB smaller and is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: The difference in sectors (7813771264 - 7813738496) × 512 bytes per sector = 16 MiB. Current LUKS versions reserve this amount for the header and keyslots/tokens (partly for possible future uses); older versions reserved slightly less (2 MiB), but some space is always needed for the LUKS metadata either way.